# Changing the data values of a form in rails based on a selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have done some searching and can;t quite find what I want. Not sure if I need Javascript for this one but wanted to check if I can do it with rails.

I have a form with two drop down inputs, :time and :time_end

Both drop downs are populated via the same method with code in my bookings.rb (below)

```
TIME = {
"08:00" => 0,
"08:30" => 1,
"09:00" => 2,
"09:30" => 3,
"10:00" => 4,
"10:30" => 5,
"11:00" => 6,
"11:30" => 7,
"12:00" => 8,
}
```

like this:

```
  <%= f.label :time, "Start Time" %>
  <select name="booking[time]">
    <% Booking::TIME.each do |name, value| %>
      <option value="<%= name %>"><%= "#{name}" %></option>
    <% end %>
  </select>


  <%= f.label :time_end, "End Time" %>
  <select name="booking[time]">
    <% Booking::TIME.each do |name, value| %>
      <option value="<%= name %>"><%= "#{name}" %></option>
    <% end %>
  </select>
```

What I want to do is this. If I select (for example) "10:00" in the :time field, when I select the dropdown for the :time_end field the only options I want available to choose are those that appear after "10:00".

Is this fairly simple or do I need some javascript here? Thank you!

Comment: This would be very easy to do with angular.js, using filters, but that would mean redesigning a large part of your application... Other than that, you could do it unobstrusively with jquery, catching a change event and filtering on the data.

Comment: Yes, JavaScript will help you. Attach a `change` event to your start time `select`, get the index of the `option` selected and then set the `option` with `index + 1` in your end time `select` to be selected. Btw, your HTML doesn't look correct: you have a `select` within a `select` and you should probably give the two `select`s different names as well.

Comment: Thanks guys. Sorry yes the select tag there is a typo. I have edited it now. I will have a look around for some examples of javascript for this as I am not too good with it. Thanks for your help :)